# Dependency on python module `sys`

Tags: ros, python, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a ROS noetic package which includes a node which imports the python `sys` module (in Ubuntu 20.04 with python3).

Is it necessary to declare the dependency on the `sys` module in the `package.xml` file?

- If yes, which `<exec_depend>` is required? I had a look at the documentation on the documentation to [python module dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html), but I have not been able to find the <exec_depend> for `sys` in the [rosditro repository](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml).
- If no, why is it not necessary to declare dependency on this import?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392016/dependency-on-python-module-%60sys%60/) by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it necessary to declare the dependency on the `sys` module in the `package.xml` file?

No.

`sys` is a part of the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library), which means it comes installed by-default whenever you install a version of the Python interpreter. Apart from that, you cannot "install" `sys` yourself as a stand-alone component or library for Python.

What you should `exec_depend` on would be `rospy`. This already depends on the correct version of Python.

Technically, your package should not depend on one of its dependencies to bring in one of its other direct dependencies (ie: if `A` depends on `B` and `C`, and `B` depends on `C`, `A` should not *just* depend on `B`, but also on `C` itself). But as `rospy` will almost certainly never drop its own dependency on Python, it would be safe to just depend on `rospy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-12-01**:
Compare this to regular Python packaging: would you add a dependency on `sys` in your `pyproject.toml` and/or `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`? If the answer is "no", then you wouldn't need to add it to your ROS `package.xml`.

**Comment by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on 2021-12-02**:
@gvdhoorn: Thanks for the detailed clarification.

So, can "would you add a dependency on `xyz` in your `pyproject.toml`?" be taken as a rule of thumb for dependencies on python packages which have to be defined in `package.xml`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-12-02**:
Any time you use something which is not part of the standard library it will have to be installed separately.

Anything that needs to be installed / present for your node to function should be expressed as a dependency.